# WebRTC. Почему не работает P2P соединение?

Tags: javascript, видео, p2p, webrtc

Решил изучить WebRTC, но у меня не получается сделать соединение peer-to-peer. 
Подскажите, что я делаю не так, может что-то ещё нужно подключить. 
Доступ к своей камере и микрофону я получаю и вижу / слышу себя.
Привожу свой код, html:

```
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>

<body>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <video id="video" autoplay="autoplay"></video>
</body>

</html>
```

JS (script.js):

```
window.onload = function () {
    var myPeerConnection = new webkitRTCPeerConnection(null);
    myPeerConnection.createOffer().then(function (offer) {
        return myPeerConnection.setLocalDescription(offer);
    }).then(function () {
        sendToServer({
            name: myUsername,
            target: targetUsername,
            type: "video-offer",
            sdp: myPeerConnection.localDescription
        });
    }).catch(function (reason) {

    });


    var usersMedia = navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
        audio: true,
        video: true
    });

    usersMedia.then(function (mediaStream) {
        var myVideo = document.querySelector('#video');
        myVideo.srcObject = mediaStream;
    });

    usersMedia.catch(function (err) {
        console.log(err.name);
    });


    var offer = getRemoteOffer();
    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
        video: true
    }).then(function () {
        myPeerConnection.onaddstream({ stream: stream });
        myPeerConnection.addStream(stream);

        myPeerConnection.setRemoteDescription(new RTCSessionDescription(offer), function () {
            myPeerConnection.createAnswer(function (answer) {
                myPeerConnection.setLocalDescription(answer, function () {

                }, error);
            }, error);
        }, error);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Во-первых - для того, чтобы видеть удаленное видео, надо добавить в код html соответствующий тег.

```
<html>

    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
    </head>

    <body>
        <script src="script.js"></script>
        <video id="myVideo" autoplay></video><!-- Это для показа локального видео -->
        <video id="otherVideo" autoplay></video><!-- Это для показа удаленного видео -->
    </body>

</html>
```

Во-вторых - может я невнимательно смотрел, но в вашем скрипте нет привязки удаленного видеопотока к объекту на вашей веб-странице.

В-третьих - даже подключив удаленный видеопоток, вы сможете получить видео только от тех, кто находится в той же сети, что и вы (например, в пределах рабочей сети, или у одного провайдера). Для работы с клиентами в других сетях, нужно включать в ваш скрипт описания STUN и TURN серверов. В интернете находится довольно большой список известных серверов такого рода, для ознакомления более чем достаточно. Можно заглянуть [сюда](https://habrahabr.ru/company/toptechphoto/blog/203306/) за подробностями.

В-четвертых (это наиболее важно, если вы действительно хотите организовать связь между клиентами в разных сегментах сети) - для хоста, на котором размещен сигнальный сервер, необходим ssl-сертификат. Иначе браузер просто не позволит передавать данные о видеопотоках.
Для ознакомления я бы рекомендовал посетить [codelab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/webrtc-web/#0) - обучающий курс от создателей webrtc. Там все описывается достаточно просто, но понятно (язык - английский).